# Login Systems and Dashboards

Tags: c#, asp.net, dashboard, login-control

I am programming a user based application with asp.net / C# and don't understand how to solve the following problems:

After the user logs in, he should be redirected to a dashboard, where he can upload photos, or change his user data, which is stored on a sql database. That's no problem, because while the user logs in, I can send the user id through the parameter for the dashboard page. But if the user changes to another pages and turns back to the dashboard, he is forced to login again.

How can I solve this problem like Facebook or Google, so the user is permanently logged in?

I hope I could explain my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.Net Identity object.  You'll probably have to do a little more than what's below but it should get you started.

Add this to your startup (I'm using some customized Identity & Role in this example):

```
services.AddIdentity<MyIdentityUser, MyIdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

then add this to your controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel obj)
        {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So instead of programming everything on my own, I can use asp.net Identity? And what is the difference to asp.net Membership?